# Cordova (or phonegap) android app loaded index.html twice

Tags: android, html, cordova, command-line-interface

I had a touble with Cordova (or phonegap) Android app for 2 weeks,the wrapped apk loaded index.html twice(the two pages overlap),then the event exuted twice too.

The details:

```
 1. I disigned a html5 page with contruct2 in which touch a image then alert "Ok";
 2. I exported the project to android or phonegap

 3. I wrapped it with CLI of crosswalk,it works fine;
 4. I wrapped it with XDK,it works fine too;

 5.I dont like these above two tools,apk size is too big;

 6.I wrapped it(pages exported  android or pages exported phonegap )  
   with CLI of cordova and CLI of Phonegap ,all fine except but the index.html
   was loaded twice (the two pages overlap) and  when touched the image, it alert  twice.
```

Can sb help me ,thanks a lot ,so Confused.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to have happened to me as well. I know this sounds crazy, but do you happen to have a space between your script tags?

```
<script src="phonegap.js"> </script>
```

I removed the spaces, and the duplication stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the sample app first and then apply your own HMTL5 page.

Follow the PhoneGap CLI app creation process here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface